# Anyway to get full bash working on Windows?

Tags: command-line, bash, kernel, windows

So I love the Linux CLI environment and I like to use bash for almost every task I can.

For some reasons too long to explain, I'm leaving my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to move to Windows 7. I have heard there are a couple of bash emulators there, like Cygwin and MSys.

My question is, can you in anyway get all the bash programs to work? For example, could I install packages using apt-get or yum or any other package provider and have them work on my Cygwin? I understand this is impossible as all the programs included with Cygwin are compiled as win32 executables, and therefore, any program provided by a package shouldn't work because they are Linux executables. Am I right?

In case this was impossible, is there any DYI way to get it solved? Could I run a Debian system on a Virtual Machine and have the bash affect the Windows filesystem? Could there be a way to run a Linux kernel directly on Windows and then load a bash from there and have it work? I'm clueless, but I'm quite excited to get to work on this project. I think the best idea would be a virtual machine, but these are normally too slow and don't affect the host filesystem, or it's hard to get it done I have heard.

Any help is sincerely appreciated. Thanks a lot guys.

Peace.

Comment: Questions about Windows should be asked on [su]. Also: http://www.colinux.org/

Comment: Use Cygwin https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: +bodhi.zazen will that allow me too download and use packages via apt-get? That's my primary question.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems not via `apt-get`. Cygwin has its own package manager, IIRC.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen But i could install any linux package could I not?

Comment: Not any linux package, only what is available in cygwin. Others you would hav eto build from source if you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin is the easiest way to use bash and other open source software on windows

https://www.cygwin.com/

I have run and X server, ssh, and KDE on windows with cygwin.

Comment: Can I install packages via apt-get in Cygwin?

Comment: No, cygwin has it's own installer. You run cygwin.exe and elect what to install.